# Improving speed of text recognition using OpenCL

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, ocr, tesseract

I'm using Tesseract's GetUTF8Text() method to extract text from an image. However, it takes about 10 - 30 seconds depending on the size of the image. Can I use OpenCL to call the same function multiple times on different parts of the image? Or does Tesseract already use OpenCL to speed up the text recognition process? I want to know if I will be able to get any speedup by splitting my image into multiple parts and extracting text using GetUTF8Text().

Comment: OpenCL cannot be used to call generic code - it is compute language + API, not a threading API.

Comment: 10-30 seconds are slow for tesseract. Do you have an example image?

Comment: OpenMP might be more aligned with your goals. One `#pragma omp parallel for` should do the trick.